# excel vba file stops working after form initialization

Tags: excel, vba, crash, listbox, userform

I am initializing a userform once user double clicks on any cell in a certain sheet. The excel file stops working after one or few initialization. Please help resolve this issue.
The form contains a list box that is populated using a multi dimensional array.This array is populated using values from a cell range that contains 6 columns and varying number of rows. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim lr, plr As Long
    Dim a As Variant


    Set psh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("P")

    psh.Activate
    lr = GetFilteredRangeBottomRow() 'function to get row number of lastrow from filtered range

    psh.Range("A1:F" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    On Error Resume Next
    psh.Range("BA1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    psh.ShowAllData
    plr = psh.Columns(53).Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'last row in column BA
    a = psh.Range("BA1:BF" & plr).Value

    With Form1.LBx 'LBx is the list box I am trying to populate
    .ColumnCount = 6
    .List = a
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use `On Error Resume Next`, That could be hiding the cause of the issue. Apart from that, how do you know Excel stops working - what error messages or symptoms do you get?

Comment: Also - use `Option Explicit` - that will show up uninitialised variables and possible spelling errors.

Comment: I will try that. To answer your question, the file crashes and excel stops working.

Comment: I noticed that the file crashes specifically when the listbox has more number of rows to display e.g. 43 rows. It seemed to work fine for 2 to 5 rows

Comment: Where did it crash if you step through? What `lr` you get?

Comment: lr may vary from anything from 2 to 65000. However I observe the issue is not dependent on lr value. It seems like the file crashes when any of the listbox contents have too long string with many characters.

Comment: What error message did you receive after you removed `On Error Resume Next`? In general, unless you absolutely know what you are doing, you should not be surpressing any of your errors. If anything, you should welcome them with open arms!

Comment: You may have encountered a size limit. This article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997541.aspx (dates back to 1992) speaks about a global limit of 32K and 64K (supposedly bytes - though 1 char needed 1 byte at that time) so you may consider it when dealing with "too long" strings.

Comment: @PatricK When stepping through it, it did not crash. I tried this multiple times. However, when I run the code, it crashes. Removing the 'Ón Error Resume Next' did not result in any error.

Comment: @AcsErno Thank you for the link. It does seem to be due to size limit. However, I do not understand why the issue does not replicate when I step through the code from VBA Editor.

Comment: what type of values are in the cells, particularly BA:BF.  Also, you are trying to push a 2-dimensional array into a List (`LBx`) - is the list box set up to take this array?.

Comment: BA: BF have strings. I am trying to push a 6 dimensional array to the listbox, which is nothing but the values present in columns BA:BF.

Comment: FYI. Since I wasn't able to resolve this issue and was running out of time, I am now using an excel range to display the output (and not list box) as an alternative. Thanks to everyone for your attempts in helping me out.